# solutions to $x^2 \equiv a \mod p^\lambda$ with $a = p^\alpha k$, $\lambda>\alpha$

Tags: number-theory

If $p$ is a prime and $a = p^\alpha k$ where $k$ and $p$ are relatively prime, when will the congruence $x^2 \equiv a \mod p^\lambda$ have solutions if $\lambda > \alpha$?

I did some quick computations on the computer and figured out that this has solutions only if $\lambda - \alpha$ is an odd number, and that too only when the following conditions are met.

For $p=3$, $k=1$, for $p=5$, $k = \{1,4\}$ and when $p=7$, $k=\{1,2,4\}$.

What is the relation between $k$ and $p$?

Comment: I assume $a,p,k,\alpha$, and $\lambda$ are all integers, aren't they?

Comment: Yes they're all integers.

Comment: $kp^\alpha$ is a square mod $p^\lambda$ iff $\alpha$ is even and $k$ is a square mod $p^{\lambda-\alpha}$.

Comment: Is this related to antisquares?

Comment: Whacka your comment should be the correct answer. Please submit it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually, this is not correct, since $x^2 \equiv 98 \mod 343$ has solutions. and $k = 98$ is not a square mod $7$. Oh well.

Comment: @Rohit Did you read my comment? Read it closer. My claim, applied to your example, is that $\color{Blue}{2}\cdot7^{\color{Red}2}$ is a square mod $7^{\color{Green}3}$ if and only if $\color{Red}{2}$ is even and $\color{Blue}{2}$ is a square mod $7^{\color{Green}3-\color{Red}{2}}$. Which it is. (Although in fact $98$ is also a square mod $7$, contrary to your claim.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way $x^2\equiv kp^\alpha$ mod $p^\lambda$ (with $p\nmid k$) is possible is if $\alpha=2\beta$ is even and $x=yp^\beta$ for some $y$ with $p\nmid y$. Then $(yp^\beta)^2\equiv kp^\alpha$ mod $p^\lambda\iff y^2\equiv k$ mod $p^{\lambda-\alpha}$. Therefore:

Claim: $kp^\alpha$ is a square mod $p^\lambda$ iff $\alpha$ is even and $k$ is a square mod $p^{\lambda-\alpha}$.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I got confused when claiming that 2 and 98 are not  squares mod 7.

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct, for exemplae if $\alpha=0$ your assertion states that:
$$x^2=k \mod p$$ has solution if and only if $k$ is odd, which is not true take $p=5$ and $k=3$, there is not solution to $x^2\equiv 3 \mod 5$

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have said $a$,$p$,$k$,$\alpha$, and $\lambda$ are all greater than $0$.

Comment: This can not be true even if you require something stronger take for exemple $x^2=3*5 mod 25$ it has no solution and $\alpha=1,\lambda=2$ and $a=3$ $p=5$, so I don't believe that there is a similar formulation which can describes the solution of the equation $x^2\equiv a \mod p^k$ other then the quadratic reciprocity:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity

Comment: True it doesn't have a solution for your values, but it has a solution for $p = 5$ when $\alpha = 2$, $\lambda = 5$, (meaning $\lambda-\alpha = 3$ which is an odd number) and $k$ is either $1$ or $4$.

Comment: To make it clearer $x^2 \equiv 9 \mod 27$ and $x^2 \equiv 25 \mod 125$ and $x^2 \equiv 100 \mod 125$ have solutions don't they?

Comment: So essentially $x^2 \equiv 9 \mod 27$, $x^2 \equiv 9 \mod 81$,$x^2 \equiv 9 \mod 243$,$x^2 \equiv 9 \mod 729$, $x^2 \equiv 9 \mod 2187$.... $x^2 \equiv 81 \mod 243$, $x^2 \equiv 81 \mod 729$, $x^2 \equiv 81 \mod 2187$.... and $x^2 \equiv 729 \mod 2187$ and so on forever all have solutions. I'm really close to figuring this out.

Comment: The crazy thing is that $x^2 \equiv 98 \mod 343$ has solutions too, for example when $x = 21$.

Comment: are your examples are similar to $x^2=a\mod p^{t}$ which have clearly solutions  when $a$ is square $a=a'^2$ (take $x=a'$ or $x=-a'$), the third case $x^2\equiv 98 \mod 343$ is a particular case for $p=7$, but like I said the equation $x^2=a\mod n$ is hard to solve in general without the quadratic reciprocity!